# The external question of these [external] tags

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

So I went on a mini-tag cleanup for [external-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-drive) since it had about 36+ items. And many of them fit perfectly into the [external-hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-hard-drive) category.

A few still are there, but they are just two BluRay questions.

That said, I found the following external stuffs:

- [external-harddrive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-harddrive): 100% empty; maybe a synonym for [external-hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-hard-drive)?
- [external-hdd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-hdd): 100% empty; maybe a synonym for [external-hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-hard-drive)?
- [external-monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-monitor): 100% empty; maybe a synonym for [external-display](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-display)?
- [external-device](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-device): 100% empty.
- [external-data](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-data): Seven items that could probably be shifted to the tag, [external-hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-hard-drive)? A few questions are good for Excel related tasks. But is there a better tag for Excel “external data” items?

So, what do people think? This should be an easy task that requires no [external](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external) contractors!

Comment: The 1st three empty ones are deprecated tags that have been synonomized.  An empty tag that isn't synonomized should be deleted by the system after 24 hrs. ([external-device]--what happened there?).  [external-drive] still shows 36 items (did you retag those with disappearing ink?).  I can see a possible use for an [external-drive] tag other than [external-hard-drive] for questions involving processes/cases that require a removable drive of some/any/multiple types, not necessarily a HDD.  [external-data]: I can see a case for the Excel usage, but the tag name is ambiguous.

Comment: Maybe [removable-drive] (with wiki excerpt guidance on usage)?  People associate [removable-media] with SD cards and the like, which often wouldn't be applicable, so it would get misused.  Actually, I see there's already a [removable] tag to clean up, with most of it's questions referring to a removable drive.  If there's a way to rename a tag, we've got a ready-made starting point.

Comment: Actually, we've already got [external-drive].  Why get rid of that?  We can just add some wiki guidance and retag some questions more precisely.  This is probably a case, though, that will always attract blurred use.  I'm not sure there's a good answer.  Some things are specific to HDDs or flash drives or optical drives, and some are agnostic.  I give up, it's making my brain hurt.